# AR in Yii add duplicate rows

Tags: php, mysql, yii, duplicates, rows

I have common model, which is generated by gii.
3 columns in mySql: id (int, A_I), setting(tinytext, null) and value(tinitext, null).
After this:

```
$cfg = new Config();
$cfg->setting = "sdd";
$cfg->value = 'dsf';
$cfg->save();
```

This effect I get even if create absolutely clear, new table and model.
This code runs in defaultAction.
Yii 1.1.4
PHP 5.5
MySQL 5.6.12
Help me, I'm tired search this bug =)

Comment: Maybe you mean to have a unique constraint on you setting field?

Comment: No, the Yii himself add double row instead one, as if script written above executes 2 times...

Comment: Did you edit the generated code, or use an edited code generator? Because it seems to me like `save()` is being called twice somewhere.

Comment: No, all components are official at once after "yiic webapp"
In the framework folder I didn't edit anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that the code runs in defaultAction. Is possible that you are calling it also in some other action. This way, the code runs twice.

Comment: Sorry for my late. The problem hides in the chrome extension, which duplicates get request to the page. Maybe this comment will help someone.